# Wordpress "Blog" template hierarchy

Tags: templates, get-template-part, blog-page

When I open up my WordPress site, and on the admin - settings - reading I define Your home page display posts as "Your latest posts" The homepage is displayed by home.php and  /blog/ is displayed by blog.php. When I change the "Your homepage displays" as "static page" and select Homepage as "home" page and blog as "blog" page, the /blog shows the home.php page and the homepage shows the page.php page. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress started as an outright blogging platform and nothing more, so the *home* page was always just meant to be the most recent blog entries, in its early iterations.

The template hierarchy has evolved since then but a lot of the labels have remained from that era.  *(Backwards compatibility and such.)*  So the `page.php` file was a later addition to WP and `home.php` file was the default *(as a blog feed)* because that was how WP started out.  You can check out the full hierarchy here.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

In short, because of legacy, `home.php` in a theme assumes that you're looking at the front page of a site that is set to having it's posts listed on it. (Like original WP.)

If you change it to static, WordPress then interprets that as you **NOT** wanting your front page to be a list of posts, so instead it assigns the default `page.php` template so that you can layout content however you see fit.

Additional templates you can have include `front-page.php` which overrides `home.php`, but you can also make whatever templates you like, for example:  `gorilla-ears.php` and then you can assign that to the page you've set as HOME in the WP Settings.  And that page can have whatever mark-up and code you want it to have.